# Where does PHPMailer Log?

Tags: php, cakephp, phpmailer

I am trying to get the Spark_plug login working with my application. Most of it is done but I don't seem to be able to send any mails. I have tried a couple of things including ensuring that the SMTP relay is correct.

But the main problem is that I am not getting any error messages, Is there a Specific log that PHPMailer writes to? I have looked everywhere I know that within the mailer class you can set debugging but this seems to have no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer itself and also Spark_plug do not appear to have any specific logging... It seems CakePHP should take care of logging for you - if set up to do so.

Comment: I have set the debug to true, but is not showing in the cake logs